# SQLite with Android Studio, return all records selected by 2 arguments

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-studio, mysqli

let's assume that i have a table with columns such as:

```
ID    SSID      BSSID      RSSI
1     abcd     hs:hd:sd    -60
2     abcd     hs:hd:po    -68
```

There are about 5000 records with the same `SSID`, slighltly different `BSSID` and the `LEVEL` values. My device is scanning the nearest environment for WiFi networks, therefore I know their MAC address and level of RSSI. I pick 3 with the highest value od RSSI.

First thing I would like to know if it is possible to search through the database to get all the records with the `LEVEL` value equal or close to `60`, for instance `59,58,61`.

Secondly, is there a way to query the database to return all the records with the same MAC addresses and RSSI values as from the 3 best scan result? If so, how would that query look like?

EDIT: Thanks for all the answers. What I'm trying to do now is to compare 3 scans with records stored in database with `getRequiredData` function. I would like to pass 2 parameters to this function, `mac address` and `level` and find records with same value for both parameters. The rawQuery seems to be fine, code is compiling but the app is crashing with the first scan. I cant find the cause of it, is it because my logic of getting these parameters is wrong or does it have something to do with query?

```
public Cursor getRequiredData(String mac, int level){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("SELECT BSSID, RSSI FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE BSSID =? AND RSSI=?", new String[] {mac, level});
    return res;
}
```

scan part:

```
class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        Comparator<ScanResult> comparator = new Comparator<ScanResult>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ScanResult o1, ScanResult o2) {
                return (o1.level>o2.level ? -1 : (o1.level==o2.level ? 0 : 1));
            }
        };
        lista = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        Collections.sort(lista, comparator);
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            scanResult = wifiManager.getScanResults().get(i);
                sb.append(new Integer(i + 1).toString() + ". " + (lista.get(i)).SSID + "  " + (lista.get(i)).BSSID + "  " + (lista.get(i)).level + "\n");
                boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(lista.get(i).SSID.toString(), lista.get(i).BSSID.toString(), lista.get(i).level);
                if (isInserted = true)
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            scanResult = wifiManager.getScanResults().get(i);
            match = myDb.getRequiredData(lista.get(i).BSSID.toString(), lista.get(i).level);
        }
        Log.i("match values: ", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(match));
        txt.setText(sb);
        wifiManager.startScan();
    }
}
```

Here is what `match` contains:

```
2018-12-10 16:36:26.334 13347-13347/com.example.maciek.wifiscann I/match values:: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@e1a86d1
0 {
   BSSID=f4:c5:ed:5c:s6:20
   RSSI=-69
}
1 {
   BSSID=f4:c5:ed:5c:s6:20
   RSSI=-69
}
2 {
   BSSID=f4:c5:ed:5c:s6:20
   RSSI=-69
}
3 {
   BSSID=f4:c5:ed:5c:s6:20
   RSSI=-69
}
4 {
   BSSID=f4:c5:ed:5c:s6:20
   RSSI=-69
}
5 {
   BSSID=f4:c5:ed:5c:s6:20
   RSSI=-69
}
<<<<<
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: How close is *close to*?

Comment: just edited and added some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the 3 rows with the closest values to 60 in column LEVEL:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY ABS(LEVEL - 60), LEVEL LIMIT 3
```

For the 2nd part of your question, you should provide sample data of the table. 
Edit: 
From the sample data that you posted I don't see a column `RSSI`, but if it exists in the table then the `SELECT` statement is ok. 
Change the 2nd parameter of `rawQuery()` to:

```
new String[] {mac, String.valueOf(level)}
```

because `level` is int. 
In `onReceive()` you use `myDb`. I don't know how you initialize it. 
If the app crashes you must copy the log, the part that identifies the problem and post it.

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. i've just added some edit to the question, if you could take a look that would be great.

Comment: Thanks for help, 'myDb' is DatabaseHelper object, which is initialized in 'onCreate()' method like this: 'myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);' .  I just found the mistake. In 'SELECT' statement 'Scans_table' was the name of the table. not 'TABLE_NAME' . Now the app is running fine, but when I looked what 'match' contains, it looks like only 'BSSID' and 'level' from 3rd best WiFi network are taken to do the query.

Comment: Your getRequiredData() has nothing to do with the 3 best WiFi network. It just returns 1 row with BSSID =? AND RSSI=?.

Answer (score 0):

> First thing I would like to know if it is possible to search through
>   the database to get all the records with the LEVEL value equal or
>   close to 60, for instance 59,58,61.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE level BETWEEN 59 AND 61;
```

- where ***your_table*** is the respective table name.
- **Note** if levels are negative (as per example data) then BETWEEN requires the lowest value first so it would be `BETWEEN -61 AND -59`.

> Secondly, is there a way to query the database to return all the
>   records with the same MAC addresses and RSSI values as from the 3 best
>   scan result? If so, how would that query look like?

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE your_mac_address_column = 'the_mac_address_value' AND RSSI = 'the_rssi_value' ORDER BY LEVEL DESC LIMIT 3
```

- Note the above assumes that the MAC address is stored in a column (if NOT then cannot be done unless the mac address can be correlated to a column).
- Assumes best LEVEL is lowest so -1 is better than -60 (if not then use ASC instead of DESC)
- Again ***your_table***, ***your_mac_address_column***, ***the_mac_address_value*** and ***the_rssi_value*** would be replaced accordingly with actual values (note that strings should be in single quotes).

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. i've just added some edit to the question, if you could take a look that would be great.